# How to change width of <p:panelGrid>

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, width, panelgrid

I have a `<p:panelGrid>` as follows:

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 50px">
    <p:row>
        <p:column colspan="2">
            <p:inputTextarea/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

I tried to set the width of the panel grid to 50px by setting the CSS `width` property, however it didn't become 50px wide.

How can I set the width of the panel grid to 50px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p:inputTextarea>` is wider than the `<p:panelGrid>` and therefore pushing it far outside the specified width.

You need to set the width on the `<p:inputTextarea>` as well.

```
<p:inputTextarea style="width: 50px;" />
```

*(note: this doesn't take margins into account, so the panel grid is still a bit larger than 50px, but you should now know how to finetune that)*

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, CSS should go in its own `.css` file.